# MySQL group by & order by & limit optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by, database-indexes

For example, I have `book_buyer` table with the following inside:

```
CREATE TABLE `book_buyer` (
    `buyer_id` bigint NOT NULL, 
    `book_id` bigint NOT NULL, 
    `description varchar(255), 
    `updated_at` datetime, 
    PRIMARY KEY (buyer_id, book_id)
);
```

Most of the time I perform all operations on the table using `WHERE buyer_id = ? AND book_id = ?`, they are unique and the prime index on them suits me, but in some cases I also just need to get a list of all book_ids. Then I resort to this query:

```
SELECT  `book_id`
    FROM  `book_buyer`
    GROUP BY  `book_id`
    ORDER BY  `updated_at` DESC
    LIMIT  15;
```

I also decided to add an index on `updated_at` to limit the sampling to 15 elements of this table:

```
CREATE INDEX updated_at_ids ON book_buyer(book_id);
```

But along with using `GROUP BY`, the explain command of the latest select query shows me that I'm still sampling ALL the fields in the `book_buyer` table - which I want to avoid. I tried adding a complex index on `book_id` & `updated_at` - didn't help, it still looks at all rows of the table. At the same time, if I remove `GROUP BY` from the select query, explain shows me that I have reached a constant of 15 units - exactly what my limit sets.

How can I add optimization to `GROUP BY` paired with `ORDER BY` & `LIMIT` to make it const/almost fixed?

Comment: I apologize in advance if this comment is deemed off topic. Does the table `book_buyer` logs the transaction when a buyer buys a book? If so, just being curios, what happens if the same buyer_id wants to buy the same book_id twice ? Wouldn't the compound PK disallow that?

Comment: Hey @blabla_bingo, it's just an example to show the problem with group by & order by indexes optimisation, the real example will not allow to insert PK twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query must do 2 sorts before delivering only 15 rows.

Technically, the `GROUP BY book_id` is invalid.  Which `updated_at` do you want for each `book_id`?  There can clearly be multiple rows for each `book_id`.

What does `updated_at` mean?  Perhaps it is when the *row* in this many:many mapping table was updated?

Perhaps you really wanted

```
SELECT  `book_id`
    FROM  `book_buyer`
    ORDER BY  `updated_at` DESC, `book_id` DESC
    LIMIT  15;
```

*That* would benefit from

```
INDEX(updated_at, book_id)
```

Note that the two columns in the `INDEX` are both in the same direction (`DESC`) and in the same order (`updated_at` first)`to match the`ORDER BY`.  Both of these are necessary for the` INDEX` to be used.  (There is a minor improvement in MySQL 8.0.)

In fact, instead of reading the entire table and doing two sorts (or maybe just one), my Select will read 15 rows from the index and no rows from the table itself.  Much faster.

Comment: What should I do if I need to distinct this query for book_ids? That's why I use group by book_id here, your solution will work, but it'll return duplicated book_ids too, so it's not my case

Comment: @Begging - if there are tuplicated book_ids, then which `updated_at` do you want?  Maybe `MIN(updated_at)`/